# glDrawArrays unexpected behavior - wrong order of arguments produces desired image

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on the code written by someone else and at the moment I have a fairly limited understanding of the codebase. Which is why I wasn't sure how to formulate my question properly, and whether it is an OpenGL question, or debugging strategy question. Furthermore, I obviously can't really share the whole code base, and the reason stuff is not working is most likely rooted in there. Regardless, perhaps someone just might have an idea of what might be going on, or where should I look at.

I have a vertex structure defined in the following way:

```
struct Vertex {
    Vertex(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 normal):
        _position(position), _normal(normal) {};
    glm::vec3 _position;
    glm::vec3 _normal;
};
```

I have a std vector of vertices which I fill out with vertex data extracted from a certain structure. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume it's another vector:

```
// std::vector<Vertex> data - contains vertex data
std::vector<Vertex> Vertices;    
Vertices.reserve(data.size()); 
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Vertices.emplace_back(Vertex(data[i]._position, data[i]._normal));
}
```

Then I generate a vertex buffer object, buffer my data and enable vertex attributes:

```
GLuint VB;
glGenBuffers(1, &VB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*Vertices.size(), &Vertices[0], 
             GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const void*)
                     (sizeof(GL_FLOAT)*3));
```

Finally, I bind a shader and set up uniforms, then I call `glDrawArrays`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, Vertices.size());
// clean-up
// swap buffers (comes at some point in code, I haven't figure out where yet)
```

At this point nothing gets rendered. However, initially I made a mistake and swapped the parameters of the draw call, such that offset comes before the number of elements to draw:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, Vertices.size(), 0);
```

And surprisingly, that actually rendered what I wanted to render in the first place. However, the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) clearly says that the offset comes first, and the number of elements after this. Which means that `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, Vertices.size(), 0)` should have shown nothing, since I specified 'zero' number of elements to be drawn.

Now there are multiple windows in the application and shared vertex buffer objects. At some point I thought that the vertex buffer object I generated somehow gets passed around in the part of the code I haven't explored yet, and uses it to draw the geometry I didn't expect to be drawn. However that still doesn't explain the fact that when I use `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, Vertices.size(), 0)` with 'zero' as the number of elements to be drawn - I see the geometry; whereas when I swap the parameters according to the documentation - nothing gets shown.

Given this scarce information that I shared, does someone by any chance have an idea of what might be going on? If not, how would you tackle this, how would you go about debugging (or understanding) it?

EDIT: Vertex and Fragment shader

Mind that this is a dummy shader that simply paints the whole geometry red. Regardless, shader is not the cause of my problems, given how geometry gets drawn depending on how I use the draw call (see above).

EDIT EDIT: Note that as long as I don't activate blending, the alpha component (which is 'zero' in the shader), won't have any effect on the produced image.

vertex shader:

```
#version 440
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=1) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 MVP; // model-view-projection matrix 

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP*vec4(position, 1.0);    
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 440
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 0);
})glsl";
```

Comment: No idea what is up with the `glDrawArrays`, but also the calls to `glVertexAttribPointer` look wrong - both configure the attribute with index 0, so the second overwrites the first.

Comment: What does `glGetError` return?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yep,sadly that's also correct in the code. I copied chunks of code into stack overflow and missed that. My apologies, I double checked, everything should be in place now.

Comment: @VTT glGetError returns GL_NO_ERROR, or in other words, zero.

Comment: @michalsrb My bad, made a type when translating it into stack overflow. It is actually correct in the code. Edited.

Comment: How does your vertex and fragment shader look like?

Comment: With outColor = vec4(1,0,0,0) I think those triangles will be fully transparent

Comment: @Amadeusz Alpha will not have any effect, so long as [blending](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm) is not enabled. And in my case it's not the problem anyways, given that the geometry gets drawn depending on how I use the draw call. Edited my answer to elaborate that part a bit more.

Comment: Are you using Vertex Array Object?

Comment: @Amadeusz Not related to the actual cause of troubles, but I did have a couple of bugs down the road that were caused by an unbound VAO. Your comment made me look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `glDrawArrays` parameter inversion, have you tried stepping into that function call? Perhaps you are using an OpenGL wrapper of some sort which modifies the order or the arguments. I can confirm however that the documentation you quote is not wrong about the parameter order!

Comment: Here goes. Turned out that the previous person who worked on the code did make a wrapper so it resembles the parameter order for the `glDrawElements`, i.e. 'count' comes second in the parameter list. As a matter of fact, his function call was something  like `drawElements` and `drawArrays`, which already should have tipped me off and make me examine stuff more carefully. Consequently, that was just a blatant oversight by me. I apologize for wasting people's time. I am not sure whether I should remove the question or keep it as a warning for those who might fall into the same trap.